# VS 2008 qgis win libraries

Tags: qgis, windows-7

I am building an app using qgis in Windows 7 with VS 2008.  It was diagnosed that I must have the wrong versions of the libraries because of a potential name mangling problem.  I have 12 unresolved externals and I can find them in gis_core by micreosoft name.  Does anyone have a different library for me to link to?

Comment: Can you please add what library you are currently using to the question

Comment: I am using the lib called c:\OSgeo4W\apps\qgis\lib\qgis_core.lib. It is dated with a create date of 11/13/2012. I downloaded it from the OSGeo4W site and the link on the main page, trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w.  I am not sure how to get the original version number of it.  It is not included in the file properties.

Answer (score 1):

Does your project have the option **Treat wchar_t as a built-in type** turned on?

Assuming QGIS is built against a default version of Qt on Windows, Qt has **Treat wchar_t as a built-in type** turned off. So the library you're linking with probably has no idea what wchar_t is

Another thing to note is that Qt is more than just a C++ library/framework. It uses its own pre-compiler (moc) to set up reflection and signals/slots in your classes. If you created your project in raw Visual Studio, it won't know to run moc against your code first before compiling it. Whereas QtCreator or a project created by Qt's Visual Studio addin does.

Comment: Yes, you are right the Treat wchar_t as a built-in type was turned on.  I turned it off and still the same results.  The same unresolved symbols.

Comment: I did a little more digging and found that I have 2 types of unresolved symbols. At least one is coming from QT. I also found a link that talks of the same problem. "[Unresolved external symbol "staticMetaObject"](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/30581-Unresolved-external-symbol-quot-staticMetaObject-quot). Since I am not building the qtcore4 library myself, I would not know where to change. This is the only QT library I am linking to. I tried versions 4.8.4 & 4.6.4.

Comment: The other commonality of symbol types are ones that include VERSION_INT as part of the name.  example: QgsApplication::mGdalSkipListVERSION_INT

Comment: Updated answer to cover Qt's moc

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am not atempting to write a QT plugin and not sure why the references were called for by the linker.  What I am trying to do is write a custom dll that currently handles device control bt needs to run a good dissolve routine on a basic shape file.  I posted my current code segment in the question "How do I add QGIS dissolve function to my C++ Windows ATL program."

Comment: Can you either tell me how I can run the moc against my code first or not require QT?